# looping through lines in a text file showing lines in Jlabel

Tags: java

I have a program which sets the lines of a txt document to a Jlabel. On the click of a JButton it is supposed to show the next line in the txt file,

The problem is the program shows the first line and functions properly but never shows another line. it allows me to keep clicking button but never switches lines...

here is my code.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Driver {

        List<String> lines;

        static String line = "";

        static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String s = "Welcome Students!";
        String b = "Start!";
        private JFrame f;
        private JPanel p;

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JButton b1 = new JButton(b);

        JLabel jl = new JLabel(s);

        int i;

        private int clicked;

        public Driver() {
                gui();
        }

        public void gui() {
                lines = readLinesFromFile();
                i = 0;
                f = new JFrame("Flash Card Program");
                p = new JPanel();
                f.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
                f.add(jl);
                f.add(p);
                p.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
                p.add(b1);

                jl.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

                // pack the frame for better cross platform support
                f.pack();
                // Make it visible
                f.setVisible(true);
                f.setSize(500, 400); // default size is 0,0
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        jl.setText(lines.get(i));
                        i++;
                        if ( i > lines.size() ) {
                            i = 0;
                        }
                        if (b1.getText().equals("Click For Answer")) {
                            b1.setText("Next Question");
                        } else {
                            b1.setText("Click For Answer");
                        }
                    }
                });


            b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                            if (clicked++ == 10) {

                                    Object[] options = { "No, thanks", "Yes, please" };

                                    int response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                                                    "Would you like more math questions? ",
                                                    "Math Questions", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                                                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options,
                                                    options[1]);

                                    if (response == 1)
                                            clicked = 1; // reset
                                    else
                                            System.exit(0);
                            }
                    }
            }); 
    }


        public static List<String> readLinesFromFile() {
            List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                scanner = new Scanner(new File("upload.txt"));
                if (scanner.hasNext()){
                    lines.add(scanner.nextLine());
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return lines;
        }

        private static void readFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException{
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            }
            scanner.close();
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        new Driver();
                        readFile(new File("upload.txt"));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: You will want to do some debugging to isolate your error. I suggest that you either use a debugger, such as contained in Eclipse, NetBeans, or most any decent IDE, and step through the code checking the state of your variables, or else use a "poor-man's debugger".

Comment: I am using eclipse no errors.

Comment: You misunderstand -- you **do** have errors, not compilation errors, which you refer to just above, but rather **logical errors**. If you didn't have them, you wouldn't be here asking this question. Use your Eclipse debugger to find them! You won't regret doing this, trust me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, poor man's debugger to the rescue:

```
public static List<String> readLinesFromFile() {
  List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
  try {
     // !! scanner = new Scanner(new File("upload.txt"));
     scanner = new Scanner(new File(UPLOAD_TXT));
     if (scanner.hasNext()) {
        lines.add(scanner.nextLine());
     }
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }

  System.out.println(lines); // ***** I added this
  return lines;
}
```

and it only reads in one line. Then I looked back to see why: you use an ***if*** block not a ***while loop***.

Change this:

```
     if (scanner.hasNext()) {
        lines.add(scanner.nextLine());
     }
```

to this:

```
     // also it should be hasNextLine() not hasNext()
     while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        lines.add(scanner.nextLine());
     }
```

So the lesson again is this: just because your code compiles does not mean that it doesn't have a bug. Using simple debugging techniques such as println statements (again, a "poor-man's debugger") is often all you need to find your logical bugs. The powerful Eclipse debugger can help you find even more.

---

Also as an aside, you'll want to change this:

```
        if (i > lines.size()) {
           i = 0;
        }
```

to this:

```
        if (i >= lines.size()) {
           i = 0;
        }
```

to avoid an array out of bounds exception.

Also your static `readFile(...)` method and static line variable serves no purpose.

Comment: You are the grandmaster of epicness! Thank you for helping and not telling me to read a book! You are a Jedi as well as the grandmaster of epicness. Have a great weekend.